# How to take params for pip from variables?

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook

I want to download files from requirement.txt file, but I need manually edit directory where I need to download them.

For example usual pip download:

```
!pip download -r C:/Users/Test/requirements.txt -d C:/Users/Test/whldir
```

But I want put it to function where will be variables for directories:

```
reqs = C:/Users/Test/requirements.txt
whls = C:/Users/Test/whldir
!pip download -r reqs -d whls
```

Is this possible to do?

Comment: download from a Python script? just use string formatting and `subprocess.Popen` (or just the latter, it will concatenate it for you), so like `subprocess.Popen(["pip", "download", "-r", reqs, "-d", whls])` (not sure about any extra arguments but this should work... I think)

Comment: @Matiiss The syntax `!pip` suggests the environment is Jupyter Notebook; the OP should have mentioned that and used proper tags.

Comment: @phd I was wondering what it was for, thanks for explaining... welp, haven't used Jupyter, not sure whether my comment is needed anymore then

Comment: `pip` itself has no such facility, but the environment probably has support for variables of some kind. You seem to be asking about `ipython` or Jupyter; could you please [edit] to clarify which tool you are asking about?

Answer (score 0):

What is that exclamation mark? What language is it? Looks like shell or windows cmd.

For windows cmd:

```
set reqs=C:/Users/Test/requirements.txt
set whls=C:/Users/Test/whldir
pip download -r %reqs% -d %whls%
```

For unix shells:

```bash
reqs="/Users/Test/requirements.txt"
whls="/Users/Test/whldir"
pip download -r $reqs -d $whls
```

Comment: Perhaps pair this with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64398183/different-ways-of-setting-environment-variables-in-jupyter-notebook

Comment: "*What is that exclamation mark? What language is it?*" Python in a Jupyter Notebook. Exclamation mark is used to run shell commands.